# @msal-browser loginPopup() method only gets the bearer token

Tags: reactjs, azure-ad-msal

I've a React App and I am using "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.13.1" NPM package to authenticate end users using Azure AD. I've registered my app and got my client id and tenant id etc which I use to populate MSAL config details but when I call the loginPopup() method of MSAL object instance, I can briefly see the popup login window and it closes by itself. I can see a successful response as a bearer token from this call. Though this is not what I want. I would like the web app user to enter their own credentials in the popup window and use it to authenticate against the AD of my org. Code is as per below ..

```
import * as msal from "@azure/msal-browser";
import {LogLevel} from "@azure/msal-browser";

const AuthService = async () => {
    const MSAL_CONFIG = {
        auth: {
            clientId: '<appclientid>',
            authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantid>',
            redirectUri: window.location.href,
            postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.href
        },
        cache: {
          cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
          storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
        },
        system: {
          loggerOptions: {
            loggerCallback: (level, message, containsPii) => {
              if (containsPii) {
                return;
              }
              switch (level) {
                case LogLevel.Error:
                  console.error(message);
                  return;
                case LogLevel.Info:
                  console.info(message);
                  return;
                case LogLevel.Verbose:
                  console.debug(message);
                  return;
                case LogLevel.Warning:
                  console.warn(message);
                  return;
                default: 
                console.info(message);
              }
            },
          },
        },
      };
      const scopes = {scopes: ["User.ReadWrite"]}
      const msalInstance = new msal.PublicClientApplication(MSAL_CONFIG);
      
      try {
        const loginResponse = await msalInstance.loginPopup(scopes);
        console.log('+++ Login response : ', loginResponse)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('+++ Login error : ', err)
    }

}

export default AuthService;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, just in case anyone else having this issue, just figured out that I needed to pass in a second value **prompt: "select_account"}** as a part of the scope.. see below...

```
const scopes = {scopes: ["User.ReadWrite"],
      prompt: "select_account"}
```

Now it opens the popup window for the user to either select an existing logged in account or user can opt for a different one by clicking 'Select a different user' option.

Answer (score 0):

version 2 for msal npm works fine with below code.

```
 import * as msal from "@azure/msal-browser";

 let config = new msal.PublicClientApplication({ // MSAL Configuration
 auth: {
    clientId: 'dynamic-client-id-as-per-requirement',
    authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + 'dynamic-tenant-id',
    redirectUri: window.location.origin,
},
cache: {
    cacheLocation : msal.BrowserCacheLocation.LocalStorage,
    storeAuthStateInCookie: true, // set to true for IE 11
},
system: {
    loggerOptions: {
        loggerCallback: () => {},
        piiLoggingEnabled: false
    }
}
})

    const msalInstance = config;

    msalInstance.loginPopup
    const scopes = {scopes: ["User.ReadWrite"]}
    const loginResponse = await msalInstance.loginPopup(scopes);
    console.log('loginResponse >> ', loginResponse);
```